# Override CSS Style in PHP Page

Tags: php, css, module, stylesheet, whmcs

I am currently writing an addon module for our Billing Software, and the modules automatically inherit the template's CSS when you use any of the elements. For example, I use the "datatable" element for my tables, and it inherits the CSS style depending upon what template the user is currently using.

I want to hide the inner border that the "datatable" element has, and I am using  tags to put all of my CSS in the module code. I am not quite sure how I can do this, but here is what the CSS looks like from the billing software's template style.css file.

```
table.form {
    border: 1px solid #B8CBE7;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
}
table.form td.fieldlabel {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #E4ECF8;
}
table.form td.fieldarea {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
.tablebg {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
table.datatable {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
table.datatable th {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
table.datatable td {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
table.datatable tr.rowhighlight td {
    background-color: #EFF2F9;
}
table.datatable tr:hover td {
    background-color: #EFF2F9;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the same **datatable** class again and set it's border as 0. You will just need to ensure this new css definition comes after the actual one

```
table.datatable { 
border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I had already given that a try and it didn't work, so I just assumed I was wrong about that. The border styling for this table must be coming from something else. Is there any way to determine exactly what is styling it?

Comment: Yes you can inspect the object in FireFox using "Inspect Element with FireBug" it will show the class from where the css style was inherited

Comment: I just realized the "borders" were actually the background div showing through due to cell spacing. I will go ahead and accept your answer as it was the first one and correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try append this line in CSS stylesheet:

`.datatable{ 
border: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: This method is important if you are working with a web application that has .css files in different areas or if you are wanting to override css from bootstrap or datatables.  One specific but common use for this method is overriding a mouse over on a table row.  specifically, I had rows that were changing based on data in the row.  The color chosen from datatables was too close to the color chosen for the rows 'status'.  I decided to use this method to override the mouse-over color to avoid confusion.